# I need to modify my code to accept multiple list of json objects in my POST request. How do we implement this ? Any suggestion would help me

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, dropwizard

I need to accept multiple lists of JSON Objects in my post request. My code is throwing an error when trying I'm giving multiple JSON Obejcts. Need some help in resolving this issue. This issue came up when working with Java-Dropwizard Project.

Here is what my code looks like.

My Resource Class ::

```
@Path("/api")
public class TestResource {

@POST
@Path("/post")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TestRes returnData(final TestRes outData) {
    return outData;
}
```

My getter and setter methods are here

```
public class JsonTransformer {

    private String Name;
    @SerializedName("Entry Date")
    private String entryDate;
    private String Description;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    @JsonProperty("Entry Date")
    public String getEntryDate() {
        return EntryDate;
    }

    public void setEntryDate(String EntryDate) {
        this.EntryDate = EntryDate;
    }

    @JsonProperty("About")
    public String getAbout() {
        return About;
    }
    public void setAbout(String About) {
        this.About = About;
    }
```

Input JSON Objects in the body of POST method ::

```
[
{
    "Name" : "Test-1",
    "Entry Date" : "01-01-1-2020",
    "About" : "Tester-1"
},

{
    "Name" : "Test-2",
    "Entry Date" : "01-01-1-2020",
    "About" : "Tester-2"
},
{
    "Name" : "Test-2",
    "Entry Date" : "01-01-1-2020",
    "About" : "Tester-3"
}
]
```

Expected Output ::

```
[
{
    "Name" : "Test-1",
    "Entry Date" : "01-01-1-2020",
    "About" : "Tester-1"
},

{
    "Name" : "Test-2",
    "Entry Date" : "01-01-1-2020",
    "About" : "Tester-2"
},
{
    "Name" : "Test-2",
    "Entry Date" : "01-01-1-2020",
    "About" : "Tester-3"
}
]
```

Comment: *"My code is throwing an error"* - And what's the error?  On what line does it occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code takes a single `TestRes` object, and you're trying to send it an array.

Change the parameter to `List<TestRes>` and then the input and your code will match.

Comment: @John just change the parameter type.

Comment: A `Map` can be used for simple objects, if you don't want to create a proper DTO for it (but you should, it's good practice). You could even accept a `JsonNode` for complicated json structures. But in most cases those would be overkill or more work than using proper DTO classes from the start.

Comment: @John you'll have to do your own research. Complex things can't be taught with simple examples.